# filtrar valores por columnas de datatframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe con un columna llamada años cuyos valores son años años quiero utilizar solo las filas de años entre 1925 hasta 2018,cómo puedo hacer esto?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes filtrarlo así

```py
df[(df["year"]>=1925) & (df["year"]<=2018)]
```

Ejemplo

```py
# Nuevo dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': pd.Series([1924, 1925, 2000, 2018, 2019], dtype='int'),
                   'desc': pd.Series(["A","B", "C", "D", "E"], dtype='str')})

# Ejemplo de dataframe
df.head()
```

[image: df sin filtro]

```py
# Filtrado 
df[(df["year"]>=1925) & (df["year"]<=2018)]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```py
# Es importante checar el tipo de dato de la columna 
print(df.dtypes)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```py
# así podríamos cambiar el tipo de dato en caso de que no sea numérico, que no es el caso aquí
df["year"] = pd.to_numeric(df["year"])
```